# Power BI - Calculating Max after summing the values for duplicate records

Tags: powerbi

I have table (Sales_Data) with Product ID and Price column wherein product ID's are duplicate eg.

[image]

From above table i want the Max value and it should be 150 i.e. for PID 2 (sum has to be happened for duplicate records to find out the max.

Below measure i created and thought it will work but no success -

`maxx( summarize (  Sales_Data, Product ID, Price),Price)`

Can you please help here to get the desired result.

Note - Sales_Data table has 58 different columns

Regards,
SK

Comment: Can you check again if your example is correct? I cannot see any duplicates in the sample table you provided.

Comment: Also, as with all Power BI/DAX formulae, the context is equally important as the data, so please, also provide desired end result, ie how do you want to display the data - in a table, in a card? Do you want the max value to be shown in every row of a table visual listing products or in a card, where there is no product context?

Comment: My mistake. updated correct example. and as a result i want the measure that will show the max value after summing the price for unique records. so with example i have given result should be 170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. What you want is alter your summarize formula like this:

`maxx( summarize (  Sales_Data, Sales_Data[Product ID], "Price", SUM(Sales_Data[Price])),[Price])`

As a note, you should consider using `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` instead of `SUMMARIZE` whenever you can. The latter is much less efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. with the correction you suggesting now i am getting the desired result.